# How to call Success or Error on binded methods (Controllers, Factorys)

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how handle success and error on binded methods that return an http response.

I am trying to bind a factory method to a controller, so I am able to call it from the view. This method will try to add an item to the shopping cart via an http request. If it fails the method that is being called will return false, however if it succeeds it will return the http response.

I want to be able to somehow add success or error callbacks to the binded method. Is this possible?

Car controller

```
// Controller to display cars page
app.controller('carsController', function($scope, $rootScope, inventoryFactory) {
// Function that will fetch JSON and save all necessary data for us to use
function init() {
    // Bind these method calls to our cart factory
    // Allow method to be called from the view
    $scope.addToCart = userFactory.addToCart;

    // Get list of items in car category
    inventoryFactory.getItems('cars').success( function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });

}

init();
});
```

userFactory

```
// Add item of given ID to shopping cart
factory.addToCart = function(itemID) {
    // Validate our user / token
    data = factory.getUserToken();
    if (data === false) {
        return false;
    }
    req = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'routes.php/api/shoppingcart/' + itemID,
        headers: {
            'X-Api-Token': data.apiToken,
            'UserID': data.userID
        }
    };

    return $http(req);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing will work, but I would recommend a few changes.

First, direct binding *may* cause problems. If your factory method at any point needs to call `this`, it will lose it, since `this` becomes the `$scope` rather than the returned object from the factory.

```
$scope.addToCart = userFactory.addToCart;  // addToCart will have "this" be of $scope
```

Whereas you can keep it either by proxying or by wrapping:

```
$scope.addToCart = function(id) {
  return userFactory.addToCart(id);
};
```

guarantees that `addToCart` inside the factory has the correct context for `this`.

Second, while you can do what you want, if you are returning a promise (as `$http()` does), then sometimes returning false and sometimes returning a promise can lead to messy code and difficulty testing. You may be better off *always* returning a promise and rejecting it as necessary:

```
var defer, ret;
data = factory.getUserToken();
if (data === false) {
    defer = $q.defer();
    defer.reject();
    ret = defer.promise;
} else {
    req = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'routes.php/api/shoppingcart/' + itemID,
        headers: {
            'X-Api-Token': data.apiToken,
            'UserID': data.userID
        }
    };
    ret = $http(req);
}
return ret;
```

This way you will *always* have a promise, and can always do

```
addToCart(25).then(function(){/* success */),function(){/* failure */});
```

If you need to do error handling, you might want to handle it inside your controller. So if your template is:

```
<button ng-click="addToCart(item.id)">Click me!</button>
```

Then your controller addToClick might be:

```
$scope.addToCart = function(id) {
  userFactory.addToCart(id).then(function(results){
     // indicate success on the screen by changing some scope var, e.g.
     $scope.message = "Successfully added to cart";
  },function(err){
     // indicate error on the screen by changing some scope var, e.g.
     $scope.message = "Problem adding to cart: "+err;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not read it yet but It is really encouraging to hear that what I am trying to do will work, as I was starting to feel like I was doing this all wrong.

I will read this shortly and give you some feedback, thanks again.

Comment: LOL! I love angular, but I think everyone does it wrong for a long time. Fabulous framework, brutal learning curve.

Comment: Since I will be calling addToCart(id) from the view, where do I include the addToCart().then.

Comment: In the view, probably in an `ng-click`? Depends on your template and business flow.

Comment: I think I misphrased my question. I am calling addToCart() in an ng-click. And i want to ensure the success / error callback will get triggered when the element is clicked. I cannot add any procedural code inline with the ng-click.

Comment: Oh, right. In that case I would put error handling in the controller `addToCart()`. I will edit above to show.

Comment: I assumed that was the way it would be donr. Again thanks alot. If i could upvote you again I would :p

Comment: No way to comment just: :-) is there :-)